# How to auto-increase the height of a FAQ with 2 Main Themes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a FAQ in my site with 2 MAIN THEMES..

I create a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/kuwr2vhn/

MY ISSUE:

FAQ B - is working OK - but FAQ A - isn't.

Both FAQ are identicals (I copy and paste) --- but....

on FAQ B I made a "TRICK" and I put a lot of  "BR" tags at end to increase manually the height of the FAQ.

FAQ A doesn't have this trick..

But this trick isn't the best way to do this - because the height will change according to the display width too.. If I have a small device - the width will be small - and the height will be different.

AND another issue - With this "BR" trick when I click on FAQ A - FAQ B will down a lot.. and for the final user it's hard to understand what happens.

I need a solution to auto-control the height.

```
// Question handler
  $('li.q').on(action, function(){

    // gets next element
    // opens .a of selected question
    $(this).next().slideToggle(speed)

    // selects all other answers and slides up any open answer
    .siblings('li.a').slideUp();

    // Grab img from clicked question
    var i = $(this).children('i');

    // remove Rotate class from all images except the active
    $('i').not(i).removeClass('rotate');

    // toggle rotate class
    i.toggleClass('rotate');

  });


 $('.faq_question').click(function() {

        if ($(this).parent().is('.open')){
            $(this).closest('.faq').find('.faq_answer_container').animate({'height':'0'},500);
            $(this).closest('.faq').removeClass('open');

            }else{
                var newHeight =$(this).closest('.faq').find('.faq_answer').height() +'px';
                $(this).closest('.faq').find('.faq_answer_container').animate({'height':newHeight},500);
                $(this).closest('.faq').addClass('open');
            }

    });
```

Comment: why do you need that height in FAQ B?

Comment: hi! I need the height in both faqs.. Without the height FAQ A doesn't open ok - you can see this in the jsdfiddle.. With the "BR" - increasing the height manually - FAQ B opens ok..

Comment: hi ! of course! the important thing is the final solution.. basic I need a FAQ with main themes (2, 3..) and all questions/answers inside.. tks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. It won't be dynamic because your answer is also a li and doesn't have its own parent. Here's way of making it dynamic.

```js
var faq_clicker = document.querySelectorAll('.faq--clicker') || document.querySelector('.faq--clicker'),
 question = document.querySelectorAll('.question') || document.querySelector('.question');

[].forEach.call(faq_clicker, elem => {
  elem.onclick = (e) => {
    let par = e.target.nextElementSibling;
  
    if(par.classList.contains('active')) par.classList.remove('active');
    else par.classList.add('active');
  }
});

[].forEach.call(question, elem => {
  elem.onclick = (e) => {
    let par = e.target.querySelector('.answer'),
        afn = document.querySelector('.answer-active');
    
    if(afn) afn.classList.remove('answer-active');
  
    if(par.classList.contains('answer-active')) par.classList.remove('answer-active');
    else par.classList.add('answer-active');
  }
});
```

```css
ul.parent, ul.answer {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.parent.active, ul.answer.answer-active {
  max-height: 500px;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="faq-holder">
  <a href="#" class="faq--clicker">FAQ A</a>
  
  <ul class="parent">
    <li class="question">
      <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> 
      What is my name?
      <ul class="answer">
        <li>I don't know also.</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="question">
      <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> 
      Who's my girl?
      <ul class="answer">
        <li>Jeamzy Chavez.</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="faq-holder">
  <a href="#" class="faq--clicker">FAQ B</a>
  
  <ul class="parent">
    <li class="question">What is your favorite food?
      <ul class="answer">
        <li>Tae.</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="question">What do I want to learn?
      <ul class="answer">
        <li>Create programming language.</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Just follow the HTML. And it will work correct. And ofcourse, edit the style. I'm not good in style that's why I just create functionalities for you.

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: Hi @herm-luna! First of all, thks for your time! This is the solution that I'm looking for. But - to be perfect - It's possible to hide the answers when I click in another answer? (as occurs in my jsdfiddle?) - This is very important to me (hide the answers) - because some answers in this FAQ are very very huge (many text) - and I need to hide this to read other just to make more confortable for the user..

Comment: yes! great! I will test here now - with my styles/animations - and made a feedback to you asap. tks a lot!

Comment: hi @herm-luna, of course! I will mark to give some points to you too! I'm testing here the code and got a issue.. I cannot "RESET" the FAQ clicking in any button.. It's a problem to me because of the very huge answers.. If I click on FAQ A button with the Questions Hidden - I need all answers hidden too.. because if I have a big answers opens the user can't see anything more, only the big answer... and may be some confuse to him..

Comment: If you changed neither markup nor javascript. You also need to change some of the code to make it work. It won't work unless you won't change it. :) Then don't forget to include the CSS above.

Comment: humm.. I understand..Another issue: I try to put a "i" (italic tag) before the question to make an arrow (and animate this to open/close the answer) but with this tag the script is broken too.. - ohh...and yes. I put the css above..

Comment: Show me your markup. I mean all. Ain't no time for convo. Just show me the code.

Comment: hi @herm-luna, don't worry!  I'm trying here something with your code (I'm not an expert in js as you..:D ) - but I'm trying..:D - here is the html: <li class="question q">
    <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>
    What is your favorite food?
      <ul class="answer">
        <li>Tae.</li>
      </ul>
    </li>